# Divide a space equally for each element

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to divide a space (or div) equally for each element without specify a an absolute value for `width`. JUST to make the CSS code flexible.

For example if you put these element into a div:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS will automatically give each `.child` element `width=50%`

And in this example:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS will also automatically give each `.child` element `width=25%`

Is it possible?

Comment: heh... probably not the answer you're looking for, but yeah. tables.

Comment: You want all `.child` to be in the same line?

Comment: @KaiQing You gave me an idea. I'll try to prove it first. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use tables I'm afraid and add a wrap for the child divs, you can do it like so:

```
#parent{
width: 1000px; /* Example width */
height: 100px; /* Example height */
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
}
.childwrap {
display:table-row;
}
.child{
display: table-cell;
}
```

Example: http://cssdesk.com/rZKRW

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery code below:

```
var childs = $('#parent .child')
    ,width = Math.floor(100/childs.length);
childs.css('width',width+'%');
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would prefer if I found a way in CSS.

Answer (score -1):

You sure can. Just apply a value with the required percent to the width property and be sure to apply a defined with to their parents. Thas all.

```
.child {
with:50%;
}
```

or for your 4 children...

```
.child {
 width:25%;
}
```

For this to work among other details the ancestor width must be specified. If the ancestor width depends on the children contents then there is a chance to hava an uncomputed width.

If your ancestor div itself hava a porcentual value, then it will be required that its ancestor to have a defined with and so on..

Comment: Thanks for your try, but I don't wanna specify an exact value.

Comment: The question was if there is a way to have the child percent automatically derived from the number of children.